# Simulating atomic action in Python

Tags: python, atomic

In Python I have an application that will use multiple threads (not multiple processes), some of which call my function stream_recv() which uses a loop to fill a buffer list message[] from an asynchronous source.  When stream_recv() this list might be empty, might not.  Thus the code snippet to pop the first message in the list is:

```
if len(messages) > 0:
    return messages.pop(0)
```

The problem is that this isn’t quite atomic (thread-safe).  If Python decides to context-switch (which it does every 5 milliseconds) while inside these statements then two different callers could get the same message and/or it could throw an exception when each such instance deletes messages[0] (the second instance would try to delete a non-existent element).

Logically Python has a countdown timer for the time-slice.  The problem would be solved if this thread timer could be restarted, even if such action triggers a context switch … at least these three statements would be guarantied to not be interrupted.  Would sys.setswitchinterval(0.005) reset the timer?  If not, how else to handle this?

BTW the execution time for the two statements on the target machine is under a millisecond with messages[reasonably sized], which fits well within the 5 millisecond default time-slice.

Comment: Do you really need to check the length of the message? Can't we just pop it without checking and ignore the exception?

Comment: Why not use a Lock or Semaphore that's shared by all threads accessing the list?

Comment: *BTW the execution time for the two statements on the target machine is under a millisecond* - ... unless the machine is under heavy load like page-fault thrashing and it takes a lot longer, or CPU overheats -> throttle the clock speed.  Or just if the OS context-switches to a different process for some time, so your Python process gets a lot less work done than usual in the 5 ms of wall-clock time.  (Unless Python uses CPU time instead of wall time for its timeslices, but swap thrashing is still possible.)

Comment: Anyway, I don't think any fixed interval until the next Python thread switch could guarantee correctness, you'd need to do something equivalent to a single-core CPU disabling interrupts before a critical section and re-enabling after.  I doubt Python lets you disable/re-enable context switches or keep the GIL held across multiple statements.